# error on binding Text='<%# Eval("PromotionId") %>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, eval

I have an issue!! I have a form that sometimes wait for a field for a table but sometime use the same form to fills the same fields but from another table, I would like to omit the binding error

I have this `Text='<%# Eval("NewAmount") %>'`
Error:

> DataBinding:'DevExpress.Web.Data.WebDataRow' does not contain a
>   property with the name 'NewAmount'

Comment: You will have to remove the binding here and bind in your code behind in the ItemDataBound event (or similar for this control).  You will have more control over what gets binded to which controls there although it will take some coding.

Answer (score 0):

your issue is related to the fact that your query not return NewAmount as field in query.You need to check your sql sintax.

If you use a simple select statement without declare the alias for the column it will return the exact table field in example :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

It return all field in table 1

```
SELECT ID,COLUMN1,COLUMN2 FROM TABLE
```

return id, column1, column2 etc

```
SELECT ID AS P, COLUMN1 AS B,COLUMN 2 AS NEWAMOUNT
```

Will return P,B,NEWAMOUNT as field instead your column name and you must bind those alias to your control. so in that case it will be

```
TEXT="<% Eval("NEWAMOUNT")%>"
```

That's all

if it solve your issue please mark it as response.

Comment: Yes, I know that the field are not going to exist, for that I would like to evaluate if Eval("NEWAMOUNT") are not exist or are null or are not binding use another field :(

Comment: you cannot bind a field which not exist.you may need the alias it is like anonymous type where from a table or data you derive a "subset" of data with custom field name.Please add relevant code about what are you doing to bind the control. aspnet page and code behind

Comment: ad also a list of field within the table so i can better understand what are you doing